# showing image for the webapp in url bar

Tags: web-applications, browser

I have a webapp for which I want to put a small image in the URL. Something similar to  StackOverflow does:

[image: favicon]

I don't know much about what is this and how it is achieved.

Comment: Oh....! I am not able to see the Image I have uploaded with this ques.

Comment: I think you're alright; we were able to see the images (and it appears that Mathieu removed the duplicate image)

Comment: @GlaciesofPacis Yes I'm very hungover and I was not sure if both images were real, so I had to edit ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That image is called a favicon. In your HTML head, insert the following:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://website.com/iconpath.ico" />
```

It looks like [this site](http://www.prodraw.net/favicon/index.php) can convert images that you have to *.ico files

Cheers!